# GitHub: Working on two repositories/branches

Tags: git, github

I have a clone of a GitHub project on my system, and I've been working on the 'develop' branch of that project. Within that, I created a folder and code that is used. So basically the structure is like this:

```
GitHub project -- master
                \ develop
                        \ my folder and code
```

What I'd like to do now, is take my folder and code contained within and start a new repository, so I can release it as a stand alone piece. So I think, in order to do that, I need to follow this guide: https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/

However I ALSO want to keep it as part of the 'develop' branch. So how can I continue working on the code, and do commits so that both the 'develop' branch as well as the new repository are updated. I want to keep both of them the same.

Is it a matter of setting up the remotes each time and issuing commits, commit once to the 'develop' branch, change the remotes and commit to the (new) repository?

Comment: You don't need to commit for each repo. Just have two remote repositories and manually push to each from the same branch.

Comment: But wouldn't the new repository, containing only my specific folder and set of files (that are within the bigger one), wouldn't that now live elsewhere, or do I 'init' and create it within the bigger one? Then commit the changes once, and push twice? (I may have confused myself earlier with the commits.) It's still confusing to me to be honest ...